# how to set all block of code collapsed by default in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In vs2010 was an Outlining option to set all blocks of code appears collapsed by default. Is there some way to do same thing in vs2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as a default.

I know it's a workaround, but as Visual Studio retains the collapsed/expanded state of the outlining when closing and reopening files you could use the Outlining -> Collapse to Definitions command to quickly collapse files when you open them and the state will be retained the next time you open that file. It's pretty quick to do and much less annoying if you use the keyboard short cut for it.

If that's too painful you'll probably need to find an extension that could do what you want, though I don't of one at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't available as a default, however you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> 
 + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> when editing a code file to collapse everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this workaround from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a694c02-f930-4787-a231-9b6932cb6121/collapse-to-defintions-by-default-ie-open-files-already-collapsed-to-defintions?forum=vseditor) (only works up to VS2012 though).

> Could you please open the marco IDE by click **Tools->Macros->Macros IDE.**
>
> You can find a modual named EnvironmentEvents in project MyMacros.
>
> Then could you please try to add this code in EnvironmentEvents?

```
Private opened As Boolean

Private Sub WindowEvents_WindowActivated(ByVal GotFocus As EnvDTE.Window, ByVal LostFocus As EnvDTE.Window) Handles WindowEvents.WindowActivated
    If GotFocus.Document Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    If GotFocus.Document.FullName.EndsWith(".cs") And opened = True Then
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions")
    End If
    opened = False
End Sub

Private Sub DocumentEvents_DocumentOpened(ByVal Document As EnvDTE.Document) Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened
    opened = True
End Sub
```